Calculate the probability of at least two identical results in 3,016 lottery draws, where 6 numbers are chosen from 49.
In a lottery where 6 numbers are drawn from a pool of 49 (1,2,...,49), what is the probability that, out of 3,016 lottery draws, at least two will have the same set of numbers?
is it:
$1 - \frac{C(49, 6) \cdot (C(49, 6) - 1) \cdot (C(49, 6) - 2) \cdots (C(49, 6) - 3015)}{(C(49, 6))^{3016}}$
or:
$1 - \frac{C({C(49, 6), 3016)}}{(C(49, 6))^{3016}}$
in both approaches, I considered using the complement principle, meaning I would first calculate 3,016 different draws.
I'm not sure if either of these approaches is correct. could someone explain the proper method to solve this problem?

First approach is correct: in the denominator you keep track of the order in which the draws appear. You should also do this in the numerator (which you do in the first appraoch, but don't in the second approach). Doing this, you have a uniform probability distribution and can use Laplace's rule for probability. Compare with the approach if you want to compute probabilities when throwing two dice. If you denote the outcomes considering order ((1,2) vs (2,1)), every pair has equal probability. Without considering order the outcome {1,2} has more chance of appearing than the outcome {2,2}.

Think about it is $ {   { 49 \choose 6 } \choose 3016} $.

Look up the birthday problem. The article generalizes beyond $365$ days and the same approach works

A standard approximation for the solution to the Birthday Problem gives the approximation $\Bbb P(\textrm{collision}) \approx 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{3016^2}{\binom{49}{6}}\right) = \color{#bf0000}{0.277}64\ldots$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations

You are correct, I have made changes to the first part

In my previous comment, the denominator of the argument of $\exp$ should be $\color{red}{2} \binom{49}{6}$.

Your first answer is correct
$\binom{49}6 = 13983816 = T,\;say $
First person  can get any ticket,$=T$
$2nd$ person's ticket must not match first one's, thus $(T-1)$ and so on for $3016$ persons against a total possibility of $T^{3016}$
For $3016$ persons,probability no two tickets match can be conveniently expressed with the numerator as a falling factorial with Knuth's notation, $\frac{T\frac{3016}{~}}{T^{3016}}$
and P(at least two tickets match ) $= 1 - \frac{T\frac{3016}{~}}{T^{3016}}$

Oh, the question (header) was about two tickets matching numbers, not about two tickets matching the winning numbers. Anyway, I am leaving that answer also as a $\texttt{possibly misguided bonus !}$


Possibly misinterpreted prize winning ticket answer
There is no point in considering the order in which the numbers appear, as they aren't considered while awarding prizes.
P(a ticket doesn't match winning combo) $= 1- \dfrac{1}{\binom{49}6} = N, $ say
P($3016$ tickets don't match winning combo) $=N^{3016}$
and finally, at least two person's tickets match winning combo  $=1 -N^{3016}$

@TravisWillse: I understand, thanks ! $;;$ :)
